# How to enable IOMMU on the debian sid Kernel

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization

I'm trying to enable IOMMU on my debian sid and with this kernel version :

```
root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario# uname -r
3.14-2-amd64
```

the motherboard of my computer is : GIGABYTE Z87-HD3

this is what happens :

```
root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario# qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 512 -boot c -net none -hda /home/ziomario/Scrivania/windows1.img -device pci-assign,host=01:00.0
qemu-system-x86_64: -device pci-assign,host=01:00.0: No IOMMU found.  Unable to assign device "(null)"
qemu-system-x86_64: -device pci-assign,host=01:00.0: Device initialization failed.
qemu-system-x86_64: -device pci-assign,host=01:00.0: Device 'kvm-pci-assign' could not be initialized
```

```
root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario# dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 00000000ba1e7d40 000090 (v01 INTEL      HSW  00000001 INTL 00000001)
[    0.000000] Your BIOS is broken; DMAR reported at address 0!
[    0.008983] dmar: parse DMAR table failure.
[    0.384339] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <joerg.roedel@amd.com>
[    0.384340] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
```

what should I do ? thanks.

Comment: Confirm its enabled in BIOS? Get a BIOS upgrade?

Comment: I think yes. Check here : http://psychonews.it/SL271507.JPG. Should I upgrade bios ? I never did it before with this motherboard...

Comment: root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario# dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 00000000badcbd40 000090 (v01 INTEL      HSW  00000001 INTL 00000001)
[    0.000000] Intel-IOMMU: enabled
[    0.000000] Your BIOS is broken; DMAR reported at address 0!
[    0.008783] dmar: parse DMAR table failure.
[    1.808564] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <joerg.roedel@amd.com>
[    1.808565] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario#

Comment: root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/usr# sudo /usr/vm1
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: vfio: error no iommu_group for device
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Device initialization failed.
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Device 'vfio-pci' could not be initialized